# select both consecutive and non-consecutive columns in data table like in group_by of dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidy

the nice thing of group_by is that it allows you to select consecutive columns with : and then if there are non-consecutive ones you can separate with ",". However, it seems you can't do that in data.table

```
library(data.table)

# create a sample data.table
dt <- data.table(a = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), b = c(1, 2, 3, 4), c = c(5, 6, 7, 8), d = c(9, 10, 11, 12))

# group by columns a, b, c, and d
dt[, .(sum(b)), by = .(a, c:d)]
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use `subset.data.table` like this:

```
dt[, .(sum(b)), by = names(subset(dt, select = c(a, c:d)))]
##    a c  d V1
## 1: A 5  9  1
## 2: A 6 10  2
## 3: B 7 11  3
## 4: B 8 12  4
```

or

```
dt[, .(sum(b)), by = setdiff(names(dt), "b")]
```

or using `slt` from the collapse package we could write the following. `select` from dplyr could also be used in place of `slt` at the expense of a few additional characters.

```
library(data.table)
library(collapse)
dt[, .(sum(b)), by =  names(slt(dt, a, c:d))]
```

Comment: It seems the names() function can be omitted in the reproducible sample I gave but cannot be omitted in my own analysis, but the one with names() works really well. However, this solution still seem a bit lengthy. Do you think there might be a shorter solution? Thank you in any case for your answer!

Comment: Have added a solution using `slt` which is a bit shorter.

Comment: I've been warned in the past (on SO) about the use of `subset`, how it self-recommends only for interactive use. I've never had an instance where using `subset` programmatically failed; the worst I've seen is when in a package function, the variable symbols (e.g., `c:d`) are warned on a package check, which can be mitigated (`utils::globalVariables`). Have you found the non-interactive use of `subset` to be fragile or risky?

Comment: @r2evans, That view is based on disliking nonstandard evaluation but if you subscribe to that then you would not be able to use all of tidyverse as well.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. There is fragility in other base functions (`ifelse` and classes, for instance), so I've been wondering (out load) if `subset` has a similar problem like that. I've not found it, I'm relieved a bit that you aren't immediately aware of a similar achilles-heel in it. Thanks.